# Why horn formulas algorithm is greedy?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I understand horn formula and it is as follow:

[image]

But I cant understand why it taught usually in the section related to greedy algorithms,
I can not see the greedy part of horn formula. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm is greedy in that it tries to build up a satisfying assignment from an unsatisfying assignment by incrementally flipping variables to be true. This can be viewed as "greedy" because the algorithm only makes local decisions (make something true in order to satisfying a specific clause without any regards to what happens later) rather than global decisions, and never backtracks from its decisions (unlike many other SAT solving algorithms).

Hope this helps!